# Web editable grid ui component for data input/updates

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, vue.js, user-interface

We use Python and MySQL on the backend. We need to expose the data input in a web app using an editable grid with insert, update, delete row capabilities and menus in some cells to be able to choose the data input. Is something Python-native available, or should we find a frontend/JavaScript framework solution?

Comment: Python runs only on server. In browser you have to use JavaScript.